# Matplotlib, live graph : setting titles and configuring subplots only works in the animate function

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter-canvas

I am developing an app that take lives data and plots it. I use funcanimation from Animation to plot the live graph. The problem is, i have to use clear() to get rid of the previous plotting. By doing so the configuration is also being resetted. The title that i set just show up for a second in the beginning and disappears. The plot is drawn into a canvas which is packed as a Tkinter widget.

Here is the related part of my code:

```
class MyPlots(plt.Figure):

def __init__(self, parent):
    plt.Figure.__init__(self, figsize=(16, 12))
    self.parent = parent
    plt.suptitle("asdasd")
    self.cList = np.array([], dtype=float)
    self.vList = np.array([], dtype=float)
    self.axes1 = self.add_subplot(211)


    self.axes1.set_title("asdasd")
    self.axes1.set_gid("A")
    self.axes2 = self.add_subplot(212)
    self.axes2.set_gid("B")

    self.m = 0.0
    self.c = 0.0

    self.start_stop = True

def animate(self, i):

    if self.start_stop:
        self.axes1.clear()
        self.axes1.set_ylim([0, 4])
        self.axes1.plot(self.parent.xList, "#00A3E0", label="firat")

    self.axes2.clear()
    self.axes2.set_ylim([0, 3])

    self.axes2.set_xlim([0, 20])
    self.axes2.plot(self.cList, self.vList, "ro")

    if self.m:
        self.axes2.plot(self.cList, self.m * self.cList + self.c, 'b')
```

The solution i've found is to configure stuff in my animate function, but it seems like a clumsy and non-pythonic way. The tutorials i have seen doesnt seem to have this problem.

The funcAnimation function calls my animate func in my controller class.

Comment: plt.suptitle("asdasd") doesnt work there but works when i put in animate for example. the set_ylim works only in the animate too